# Created repositories with svn 1.8 have format 5 instead of 6

Tags: svn

I just installed svn 1.8.1 from wandisco to use the new features of 1.8. When I create a new repository using

```
svnadmin create test6
```

The format is still 5 (like in <=1.7) in the file test6/format.

```
# svnadmin --version
svnadmin, Version 1.8.1 (r1503906)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I looking at the wrong place for the new format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the question  and answer https://serverfault.com/questions/277441/difference-between-the-format-and-db-format-files-in-a-subversion-repository, that explains the difference between repository format and file system format in great detail. When you look at `test6/format`, you see there the repository format, you should look at `test6/db/format` to see the file system format you expect. There, it should be number 6.